# Хранение файла конфигурации

Tags: php

Подскажите, в каком случае достигается наиболее высокий уровень безопасности хранимого файла конфигурации ?

```
    1 - .ini и запрет по .htaccess
    2 - перемещение файла конфигурации за пределы папки root хоста (например, у nginx, говорят, самое то)
    3 - .php 
    4 - БД
```

Если есть другой вариант, буду рад послушать )

Comment: Все хороши, если не косячить с настройкой.

Comment: В .php можно хранить конфигурацию, исходный код будет виден только в том случае, если кто-то войдет на сервер, а иначе простой юзер не сможет увидеть что-либо.

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы все делаете осторожно и как следует, то ни у кого не будет доступа к файлам конфигурации даже если они лежат в рутовой папке проекта. 
Да что там говорить при адекватной настройке можно сделать так что бы этот файл был недоступен даже если ФТП в папку где он находится.. 
К примеру в Laravel - конфиг файл хранится в корне проекта, и это никому не мешает. 
в Ruby on Rails - точно так же..

А вообще интересную стать видел давно. 
https://habr.com/ru/post/330772/ 
Стоит ознакомится

Comment: Спасибо, прочту )